# Solve for x, y and z

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x+y-2z=5  (1)\\
 x   +z=4  (2)\\
     -z=6  (3)$$

$$2\cdot(2): 2x+2z=8 (4)\\
(1)+(4): 3x+y =13 (A)$$

$$(2)+(3): x=10 (B)$$

$$(A)-(B)= 3+y=3\\
     y=3-3\\
     y=0$$

Substitute $y$ into $(A)$

$$3x+y=13\\
3x+0=13\\
x=\frac{13}{3}\\
x=4.333$$

Substitute $y$ and $x$ into $(1)$

$$x+y-2z=5\\
(4.333)+(0)-2z=5\\
4.333-2z=5\\
z=\frac{9.333}{-2}\\
z= -4.666$$

Please show me where I made a mistake.
Sorry for the unorthodox method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtracted equation (B) from equation (A), you should have obtained

$$2x + y = 3$$

That said, that step was not necessary.  Since you had already obtained $x = 10$, you could have substituted $10$ for $x$ in equation (A) to obtain

\begin{align*}
3(10) + y & = 13\\
30 + y & = 13\\
y & = -17
\end{align*}

then found $z$ by multiplying equation (3) by $-1$.

Allow me to point out a simpler method.

\begin{alignat}{6}
x & + & y & - & 2z & = & 5\\
x & & & + & z & = & 4\\
& & & - & z & = & 6
\end{alignat}

Multiply the third equation by $-1$ to obtain $z = -6$.  Substitute $-6$ for $z$ in the equation $x + z = 4$ to obtain $x - 6 = 4 \Rightarrow x = 10$.  Substitute $10$ for $x$ and $-6$ for $z$ in the first equation to obtain $10 + y - 2(-6) = 5 \Rightarrow y = -17$.

Answer (score 2):

$(A)-(B)$ should give you $(3x+y) - x = 13-10$, so you $x$ does not dissappear.

Comment: In addition, the value of $x$ was found from $(B) = (2) + (3)$, and the value of $z$ is known from $(3)$.

Comment: @mardat That is true, but technically not a mistake.

Comment: If I substitute 10 into the first equation I get -5 instead of 5?

Comment: @HeinTerblancheseemykungfu. Yes. You then only need to calculate $y$ and $z$, since you already have $x$.